# What are AT commands ? When to use them?

Tags: bluetooth, at-commands

I read some articles about the AT commands but I am still unable to understand something. As the article says "AT commands are instructions used to control a modem."
I used a while ago an Bluetooth module(HC-05) to control a RC car and I saw that the module recognise AT commands. I could control the car using only UART communication and at that moment I just ignored the AT commands. 
 So, why does the Bluetooth uses AT commands ?

Comment: Some quasi-modern devices use AT commands because they historically fit into roles or patterns of designer/user thinking dating back to smart wireline telephone modems that used them.   Beyond that the question is too broad and off topic.

Comment: "AT commands" is a somewhat standard control protocol built mostly on top of serial interfaces. It is an ASCII protocol and can be used to enter commands "by hand" through a serial terminal of some sort. Other than that the reasons are mostly historical.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is referring to 'smart modems used with telephones', not necessarily modems used with smartphones (indicating that this is ancient command set). So yes, there's much history, and inertia with the use of AT commands.  There is however, no reason one must use them.  Once learned, they are human readable.  Other than that, no benefit that I'm aware of.

Comment: Semi-standardization would be a benefit.  For example, the Linux chat daemon can talk them; even *non-standard vendor extensions* because they have the same *form* regardless of the details.  A custom scheme could need new *software*, not just new *data*.

Comment: It's important to note that Bluetooth itself doesn't use AT commands. It just happens that the Bluetooth device is configured as a serial device that responds to AT commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can configure the HC-05 module with AT commands. Sometimes you want to change the baud rate of the module, the role (master - AT+ROLE=1 /slave - AT+ROLE=1), to get module Bluetooth address(AT+ADDR?),or to reset the configuration (AT+ORGL). 
Take a look here to see how to enter in AT mode and how AT commands look like: 
http://www.linotux.ch/arduino/HC-0305_serial_module_AT_commamd_set_201104_revised.pdf